# CSS Animation not working when use Media Queries in IE

Tags: html, css

I use CSS Animation and media queires  [like this!](http://jsfiddle.net/supachai_pay/hF7SW/)

```
HTML
<div class='block'>
    <div class='block-bar'></div>
</div>
CSS
    .block-bar {
        -webkit-animation: timebar 1s infinite;
        -moz-animation: timebar 1s infinite;
        animation: timebar 1s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes timebar {
        0% { width: 0%; }
        99% { width: 100%; }
        100% { width: 0%; }
    }
   @-webkit-keyframes timebar {
        0% { width: 0%; }
        99% { width: 100%; }
        100% { width: 0; }
    }
}
```

it work correctly in Chrome and Firefox but not working in IE

How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Media queries are not supported until IE 9 ... http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Comment: Only IE10 support keyframe animations. So if you are using IE9 it's normal not to work. (and learn to say what version of IE you are talking, treat IE as 4 different browsers IE7-8-9-10)

Comment: Thank you, i work on IE 11, it not working too.

Comment: No way to test it on IE11 but it works in IE10. http://jsfiddle.net/G4ddZ/

Comment: In your fiddle it not working when i put @media only screen and (min-width:321px) to cover all css. why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that IE doesn't like it when keyframes are defined within mediaqueries. If you pull the definition for the keyframes outside the mediaquery it works. (Tested in IE11)

```
@keyframes timebar {
    0% { width: 0%; }
    99% { width: 100%; }
    100% { width: 0%; }
}

@media(min-width: 300px){  
    .block-bar {
        height: 50px; background-color: red;
        -webkit-animation: timebar 1s infinite;
        -moz-animation: timebar 1s infinite;
        animation: timebar 1s infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes timebar {
        0% { width: 0%; }
        99% { width: 100%; }
        100% { width: 0; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is obscure. IE11 doesn't error, doesn't say anything. All the animation properties that aren't working still show up in the Inspector, just with unexplained "overridden" lines through them even though nothing's overriding them. This is a clientsaver.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm trying to get out of this