# How to make css animation active only for some screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, screen-resolution

I am creating an animated logo for website running on WordPress and I want to know if it is possible to make the css animation possible only for desktop resolutions. I think the animation would not work for mobile version and I want to have different css for mobile versions.

Is it possible to put the @keyframes into @media screen and (min-width: 1000px){...}  ? Just combine it somehow?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Animation not working when use Media Queries in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161022/css-animation-not-working-when-use-media-queries-in-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `animation` property inside a media query.

```
@keyframes myKeyframe {
    from { top: 0; }
    to { top: 100px; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    #myDiv {
        animation: myKeyframe 1s;
    }
}
```